# How to make a horizontal navigation bar that have different background colour blocks

Tags: css

I want to make a nav bar that have different colour blocks. I am developing a website please help me! I want to make it more attractive. Also tell me that which is the best website to learn Css , php ,HTML and more....thank you so much

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many places on the web that can help you out. For some quick basics the ***w3schools*** website is handy:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

For some step by step tuition, you can use sites such as ***codeschool*** and ***codeacedemy***. Both offer free lessons to start you off and are well put together.

http://www.codeschool.com

https://www.codecademy.com/

My advice would be to learn some HTML, then CSS and then look into PHP.

Good luck! :)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I know that w3schools is best website for basics I am learning from it only I have already learn some html and css php I have not learned but I am going to use it for making my login register form and in many things I know to make a simple nav bar but I want to make a colorful nav bar can you help me more please

Comment: You will need to learn some CSS to make it colorful.  You may find it easier to look at using the Bootstrap framework. there is a good starting point for you there. This person has made a navbar generator (which is based on the bootstrap navbar) so that you can change modify the look and feel. http://twitterbootstrap3navbars.w3masters.nl/